# Set up Tomcat server on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, installation

I need to get a local setup of Java working so I can start coding locally and doing builds.

I know that Java is built into macs automatically. I am running version 1.6.0_22

I found an article on how to install tomcat:
[Tomcat on a Mac](http://developer.apple.com/internet/java/tomcat1.html)

I got the Tomcat server running to where i can see the default Tomcat Page.

Started to dig deeper but hit a huge wall on getting to a point where i could use an IDE to get coding.

I downloaded Eclipse for the mac (because it was free and seemed to be the more popular one out there)

So where do i need to go from here to get a working environment to test code from our svn?
Any good articles that i can read. It was hard to find some (recent) documentation on how to get this working on a mac.

Comment: It's `Java`, not `JAVA`.

Comment: Thanks, learning this all on the fly. I come from a PHP and front end prospective and trying to get a local dev environment on my mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Eclipse did you download? I'm guessing you downloaded [*Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1), which doesn't have the nice WTP stuff that you probably want.

You'll need a heavier flavor of Eclipse, like [*Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1). I'm not sure if there's a lighter (in-between) flavor that has WTP, etc., without all the Java EE stuff.

Comment: Yah i just got the normal download for mac for Eclipse.

Comment: @estern: try the Java EE flavor.

Comment: WTP == Java EE Stuff. Once you get yourself the Java EE distro, start it up and look under the Help menu for marketplace. Click on that and search for SVN. There are two plugins available. Both are pretty good. Pick one and go from there. Search for "Eclipse Tomcat tutorial" to find articles on getting started with development.

Comment: @Konstantin: I think you misread me: that there might be (but I don't know if there is) a flavor that has the web-only parts of WTP but not the _more_ Java EE parts (EJBs, ORMs, web services, etc.). WTP == [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), which has Java EE subprojects like like [EJB Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ejb/) and [Java EE Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jee/) (yeah, not the best names...) but it also has more web-centric parts like [JSF Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/main.php) and [JS Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt).

Comment: There isn't a ready-made distribution like that, but someone who knows what they are doing can put one together from the update site. Not something that I would ever recommend to a novice, especially since Tomcat is a Java web server (part of Java EE spect). You cannot even install non-Java portions of WTP and still be able to use Tomcat. You have to install non-Java portions and Java web app development features.

Comment: @Konstantin: so it sounds like the simplest option, though perhaps bloated, is Eclipse for Java EE Developers, correct?

Comment: Yes, I would use "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" when working with Tomcat. The amount of bloat over what is necessary is very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some sort of SVN client and know how to create a trunk on your local machine, do that, and then all you have to do from there is open the java project in that trunk within Eclipse. Once you have that open, on the Eclipse toolbar just build your code, make sure that works, and then run it in the same fashion.

Comment: What would the project file end with in my svn project files? file.imi, file.iws, file.ipr, pom.xml?

Comment: Well if the SVN files have never been worked with in Eclipse before, you might just see a bunch of .java files. If that's the case, just open all of them in Eclipse and then try building...